# Azure mySQL Password Expired

Tags: mysql, azure, laravel-5

Hi I am using Azure web services. And I am using Laravel and mySQL. Until yesterday everything was working fine and I didn't updated any files.

Today I am trying to go to my page that creates a user and I see this error

**ErrorException in Connector.php line 119:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1862] Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. (View: D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\resources\views\user.blade.php)**

When I try to go to **phpMyAdmin** I see this error [image: phpMyAdmin Error]

I pressed **Retry to connect button** but it did not work
I tried enabling and disabling my mySQL service in Azure but I get the same error.

**Is there any other way I can use my azure console etc to change mySql password?**

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Application Setting** on Azure Add **Key = WEBSITE_MYSQL_ARGUMENTS** and **Value  = --default_password_lifetime=0**

Answer (score 0):

I've problem with my AZURE App Service (Wordpress), all of the sudden the page shown blank white page with only message "Error establish database connection" (or some like that)

I've enabled the Logging by follow this [Enable WordPress Error Logs on Azure App Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/10/09/logging-php-errors-in-wordpress-2/) , then looking at both d:\home\LogFiles\php_errors.log and d:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\debug.log (keep reading at the [Enable WordPress Error Logs on Azure App Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/10/09/logging-php-errors-in-wordpress-2/) down until Q&A) were lead to the same clue, "Your password has expired..... blah blah",

Using the above method by @Alexander works pretty and fixed the problem immediately without any restarting required, just refresh the browser.

Comment: Thnx for appreciation!